# Get the tag "a" from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

This is my code, i need to get the tag "a" from the iframe but when i get it i get an empty array like this: [Empty array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04RbC.png)

```
const frame = this.pdfViewer.iframe.nativeElement
    const frameArray = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("page")[this.pdfViewer.page - 1].getElementsByTagName("a")
    console.log(frameArray)
```

but when i open it i have this: [This is the "a" on my array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAlsi.png).
How can i get the tags?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)

Comment: Mmmm i don't thinks so, i think that my problem is that the html is loaded after the JS, or am i missing somehting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`const frame = this.pdfViewer.iframe.nativeElement const frameArray = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("page")[this.pdfViewer.page - 1] console.log(frameArray.getElementsByTagName("a"))`

Comment: Same problem :(